# Best approach to show notification of "Add to Wishlist" using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

**Scenario**: I want to show notification to user once product is added to wishlist

I have already implemented this code & its working but I want to know the best approach of doing this using angular features. I have used `$rootScope` for this. Below is the code:

**In Controller**:

```
$scope.addToWish = function (product) {
    var user = checkUserLoginStatus.getIsUserLoggedin();
    if (user == ""){
        $('#ModalLogin').modal();
    }else {
            DataRepository.saveProductsToWishList(product); // service

            $scope.$watch($rootScope.addedToWishList, function () {
               $timeout(function() {
                 $rootScope.addedToWishList = false;
                }, 4000);  // to hide alert after 4 secs
            });
    }
}
```

In `DataRepository` service, I am updating value on `$http` **success** function

```
$http({

   // Some POST call
 })
 .success(function (response)
   {
     $rootScope.addedToWishList = true;  // this makes ng-show true on html
     $rootScope.$emit('WishList modified', response);

   })
```

Comment: Is your notification in a directive? A better option would be to emit a event on your controller scope that your notification directive lisens to. It can then deal with hide the notification after a period of time. Best to not have that logic in your controller. It would also make it easier to extend to make it a general notification module where messages could be stacked up, you could pause the hiding of them if the user hovers on them etc.

Comment: @ste2425: Thats also a good approach from existing code. Its simply a div. This is really a valuable comment. i'll keep this mind. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return the `$http` call from `DataRepository` you can chain a `.then` to it like so:

**Controller:**

```
$scope.addToWish = function (product) {
    var user = checkUserLoginStatus.getIsUserLoggedin();
    if (user == ""){
        $('#ModalLogin').modal();
    } else {
        DataRepository.saveProductsToWishList(product)
            .then(function() {
                // show wishlist message
                $scope.wishlistMessage = "Added to wishlist";

                $timeout(function() {
                    // hide wishlist message
                    $scope.wishlistMessage = "";
                }, 4000);
            });
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
function saveProductsToWishList(product) {
    return $http({
        // some post call
    });
}
```

[In general you want to stay clear of the rootScope.](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil)

Comment: @Shashank You can find a cool read about promises here: http://solutionoptimist.com/2013/12/27/javascript-promise-chains-2/